# Can't find Monodevelop's mdtool on my system

Tags: windows, monodevelop, solution

When I'm on my linux system, I can build Monodevelop solutions from the shell with mdtool.  But my windows sytems don't seem to be able to do that.  I've searched the hard disk for mdtool.* but don't see it anywhere.  Is my Monodevelop install broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though it's `mdrun.exe` on my Windows setup.

Answer (score 0):

If using Xamarin Studio on windows, it is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\bin\mdtool.exe
```